# Circular Prime number in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a haskell code that takes in a number and determines if it is a circular prime or not. A circular prime is a prime number that is prime even if it is arranged in different order. I have written the following code:

Edit:

```
prime :: Integer -> Bool
prime a
   |factor a == [1] = True
   |factor a == [a] = True
   |otherwise         = False

factor :: Integer -> [Integer]
factor a = [x | x <- [1..a], mod a x == 0]
```

The code should print the following when filter function is applied to it:

```
> filter circprime [2..100]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,31,37,71,73,79,97]
```

But it only prints `False` and that:

```
 > filter circprime [2..100]
    []
```

Can you help me with this please.

Comment: Why do you post a complete duplicate of your earlier question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611655/circular-prime-numbers-in-haskell

Answer (score 2):

you need to create the circular rotations, easier to work with lists instead of numbers

```
rotate [] = []
rotate (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

well, you need as many as number of digits (although some may not be unique)

```
rotations n = take (length n) $ iterate rotate n
```

using `length` can be avoided but in this domain should be fine

now you need to convert the integer to list and back, using `read/show`

```
map (read :: String->Integer) $ rotations $ show 123
[123,231,312]
```

what remains is calling `prime` for each element